fopen(laravel-project/storage/framework/cache/..) error
I'm running Laravel 10 application on Ubuntu server with php 8.2
I have login working and every page is working just fine. But after about 2 hours, I'm starting to get this error on multiple auth protected pages:
fopen(laravel-project/storage/framework/cache/data/be/40/be4029be9c8762788e0e906d2e0a2e56c21f9150): 
Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at 
/var/laravel-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php:69

I've set 777 permissions to all folders inside storage & framework (I know it's overkill, but was trying to make it work)
I did php artisan cache:clear multiple times, which is a temporary solution for ~2 hours
I rebuilt the project/updated composer
Need ideas for further debugging

What settings do you have in your config/cache.php?
Where are you hosting your application, is it on your own machine or a paid service such as AWS, Digital Ocean, etc?
